# limits of integration of a function of joint probability density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to do an exercise of joint probability distributions in which I ask to show that the pdf is a valid pdf

$$ f(x,y) =\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
            \frac{3(x^2+y^2)}{16} & \text{if }0<x<y<2 \\\\
             0 & \text{else} \\\\
           \end{array}\right.$$

to demonstrate that it is a valid pdf I have to integrate all $\mathbb R$, however as the function is non-zero only on the interval $0 <x <y <2$. As would be the limits? I have serious doubt that.  there any way to get those limits?

Comment: But your function is defined everywhere! It's $0$ whenever we are not in the interval $0<x<y<2$.

Comment: sure, but I only want to integrate in the given interval to see if the double integral results equal 1

Comment: I suggest you edit "..as the function is only defined on the interval.." to "..as the function is non-zero only on the interval..".

Comment: Indeed, it was a bad translation because if this function outside the range defined by taking the value zero. Excuse my english

Comment: The set $0\lt x\lt y\lt2$ is not an interval.

Comment: You would find this problem a _lot_ easier if you were to sketch a diagram of the plane with $x$ and $y$ axes, and figure out the _region_ of the plane where the joint probability distribution is nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the interval $0<x<y<2$. Now $x$ can take any value between $0$ and $y$. Thus we obtain:

$$\int_0^y \frac{3(x^2+y^2)}{16} dx$$

Now $y$ can take any value between $x$ and $2$. Moreover, since $x$ can take any value greater than $0$ we have that $y$ can take any value between $0$ and $2$. Thus we obtain:

$$\int_0^2\int_0^y \frac{3(x^2+y^2)}{16} dxdy$$

Evaluting this integral gives $1$ as desired.